# Usage of Matplotlib Hexbin

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to get a hexbin map similar to this example: https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/hexbin-map-from-geojson-python.

But with the map of Barcelona. So, I started with this code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
map = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/rojas/Google Drive/Documentos personales/Pruebas Hexbin map/hexbinmap_prueba/BCN_ContagiosEtapaI.geojson")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Set the plot size for this notebook:
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=12,12
# Draw a map with matplotlib
geoData.plot(color="white", edgecolor='black', linewidth=.5);
plt.axis('off');
```

With precedent lines I get a "normal" map, so I was checking the `matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin` documentation (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html) in order to get the Hexbin map. The following appears in the information:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin(x, y, C=None, gridsize=100, bins=None, xscale='linear', 
yscale='linear', extent=None, cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, 
linewidths=None, edgecolors='face', reduce_C_function=<function mean at 0x7fcc1b66a310>, 
mincnt=None, marginals=False, *, data=None, **kwargs)
```

I don't know what to put in the "x" and "y" position. Does anyone have a tutorial or similar to use this package?

Comment: I think you're looking for this tutorial: [Hexbin map from geoJson with Python](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/hexbin-map-from-geojson-python)

Comment: @tdy indeed. Already edited the question.

Comment: The "Load & merge numeric data" section of that tutorial shows how to fill the hexbin colors. It doesn't use `pyplot.hexbin`.

Comment: @tdy Sorry, did not understand your first comment. I already checked that tutorial (is the first link attached in my question). My concern is how to get an hex map from a "normal" map: if you see, the first code I wrote in the question is the same that the tutorial from, but didn't get the same result. That's why I think I should use the `pyplot.hexbin`.